# A sporting word puzzle

Tags: word

Here is another word puzzle.  What does the arithmetic work out to?

```
(Baseball x Cricket x Netball) - (Basketball x Rugby Union x (Rugby League - Polo))
= ?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it could be

> Australian Rules Football

but only if

> you mean to put parenthesis around (Rugby League - Polo) 
>  if so, then then using the number of players on a team gives: 
>  Baseball = 9 
>  Cricket  = 11 
>  Netball  = 7  
>  Basketball = 5 
>  Rugby Union = 15 
>  Rugby League = 13 
>  Polo   =  4 
>  making the formula come out to be 18, the number of players on an Aussie Rules Football Team

Comment: Even with the typo! That's great.

Comment: I figured there might’ve been a typo, great answer Steve!!

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with

> Number of players on a team.

So: (Baseball x Cricket x Netball) - (Basketball x Rugby Union x Rugby League - Polo)

> $= (9 \times 11 \times 7) - (5 \times 15 \times 13 - 4) = 693 - 971 = -278$

Comment: The answer should be a word.